# Pretty user-interface with animated segue in Swift

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift, uigesturerecognizer, segue

I want to make a pretty interface. So after reflexion, I decide to make a pattern with to axes but with some essential points. The red screen is the primary screen, all start by this one. 
We can only make this two move : red to another color and another color to red. And change are made with GestureRecognizer.

[image]

I also want to switch view by seeing the two at the same time. Obviously, it's following my finger and I can stay in this state.

[image]

Do you think that 5 viewController witch are all load at the start and we came to these with pretty segue (maybe custom) is possible ? And if yes, do you have an idea of how to make this ?

Answer (score 1):

As a first thought I think you want to make a custom view controller navigation controller. Like `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController` or `UIPageViewController`.

I'd also use a scroll view over a gesture recogniser maybe?

Either way it's gonna be a lot of work which means there are many many different ways to do it.

It sounds like you have a decent idea of how you want it to work. Give it a whirl and see what happens. I reckon you can have a decent bash at it.

If you get stuck let us know and we'll try to help :)

Comment: Yeah, I will certainly use a TableView.
I'll look for a customNavigationController. Thanks.
Do you know a good place to learn how to make it ?